# Why would Scala Range iterator buffer -- sometimes?

Tags: scala, memory, iterator

In Scala 2.9.1, this works fine:

```
scala> (1 to Int.MaxValue).sum
res6: Int = -1073741824
```

Yet this runs out of heap space:

```
scala> (1 to Int.MaxValue).toIterator.sum
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

But maddeningly, this works:

```
scala> (1 to Int.MaxValue).iterator.sum
res8: Int = -1073741824
```

Why should any of those be different?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`toIterator` is defined in `TraversableLike` as

```
def toIterator: Iterator[A] = toStream.iterator
```

so it creates a `Stream` in the background which keeps all elements in memory while iterating.

(**Edit**: I think the stream structure isn’t the problem here actually. However, `toStream` itself calls `toBuffer` which in turn copies every single value.)

`iterator` on the other hand is defined in `IndexedSeqLike` which uses a specialised structure which does not keep any elements in memory.

Comment: In other words, it's a bug; classes with an `iterator` method (at least immutable ones) should override `toIterator` to simply call `iterator`.

Comment: Yeah, the nightly fixes that.

Comment: I'm using 2.10.3 and (1 to Int.MaxValue).iterator.sum consumes tons of memory for me. I can't get why..

Answer (score 2):

If you take a closer look at the code, it's how everything is defined.

When you call toIterator, it takes everything in the sequence and copies it into an ArrayBuffer (by first trying to convert it to a stream.)  This copy is likely what causes you to run out of memory.

When you use iterator, it creates an instance of a protected class Elements that returns a BufferedIterator.  This uses the class itself to return elements.

```
protected class Elements(...) ... {
    ...
    def next: A = {
        if (index >= end)
            Iterator.empty.next

        val x = self(index)
        index += 1

        x
     }
}
```