# Scala Range iterator memory usage

Tags: scala

There was exactly the same question 2 years ago:
[Why would Scala Range iterator buffer -- sometimes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244600/why-would-scala-range-iterator-buffer-sometimes)

Though it has an answer, it seems it's not valid anymore. I'm playing with 2.10.3 Scala and I have very high memory usage in this code:

```
val s = (1 to Int.MaxValue).iterator.sum
println(s)
```

I looked through the sources of IndexedSeqLike and I can't find where buffering is happening.

Can someone experienced with Scala explain if that correct behavior or bug and maybe point me in sources where does it buffer?

Comment: Sure that's not your use case. You will wait pretty long for that to calculate and it will overflow 32 bit signed Int. (1 to n).sum can be expressed as n(n+1)/2. Anyway I can let that expression run and it doesn't throw an out-of-memory error, so I doubt that it creates a representation of the individual elements.

Comment: There is implicit boxing of integers (iterator isn't specialized), so you're using java.lang.Integer, not primitive ints, perhaps that is the case of high memory usage, not the mystery buffering? Iterator.range should be more memory effective.

Comment: om-nom, you are right! I made summing manually in a loop and added Int.box call there and I'm seeing exact memory usage. You should add that as an answer I think, thanks!